# JSON Logs in Google Cloud Logging using Winston in nodeJS

Tags: syslog, winston, google-cloud-logging

I am running a nodeJS server on Ubuntu 14.04 in Google Compute Engine. I want to use google cloud logging for my application so I installed google fluentd logging agent as per https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation

I used winston and winston-syslog for writing logs. Here is the code.

```
var winston = require('winston');
var winstonsyslog = require('winston-syslog').Syslog;

var options = {
    json : true
};

winston.add(winston.transports.Syslog, options);
```

When I am writing a log using

```
winston.log('info', "27", { anything: 'This is metadata' });
```

I am getting

```
{
  metadata: {…}    
  textPayload: "May 14 10:47:44 localhost node[7633]: {"anything":"This is metadata","level":"info","message":"27"}"    
  insertId: "..."    
  log: "syslog.local0.info"    
}
```

How to get structPayload instead of textPayload which displays log as JSON instead of String.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue.. I gave up in the end.. The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging#cloud_logging_and_the_flexible_environment) state that you should name your logs with the suffix `.log.json` and that you should have an inline valid JSON object on each line.. though even with this I was unable to read it through Googles cloud logging....

FYI: Your log, as in "testPayload" is not a JSON object

Comment: I am using gcloud nodeJS client now for logging to google cloud logging service. Somehow it works https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.34.0/logging/log

Comment: I think that's because it taps into Googles underlying fork of fluentd... I was able to get logs working by imitating the same format found [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_index#common) .. although i think the right way to do it is using the [logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/)

Answer (score 0):

Logging agent has it's own configuration files, and most of them have `format none` (see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluentd-catch-all-config). Thus, all log lines go to `textPayload`.

The solution is to write your own fluentd configuration file and use [fluent-plugin-google-cloud](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-google-cloud) as output. fluent-plugin-google-cloud should be installed as a gem **directly**, not using Logging Agent As long as your entry is a valid JSON, you will see that entry on Stackdriver having `structPayload` set properly. Key/value filters work as well.

I have never used winston, but here is sample configuration:

```
<source>
    @type tail
    format apache
    path /var/log/apache/access.log
    tag apache.access
</source>

<match **>
    @type google_cloud
    buffer_chunk_limit 10k
</match>
```

Notice the `buffer_chunk_limit 10k`, setting it to values too big or leaving it at default may result in `Google::Apis::ClientError badRequest: Request payload size exceeds the limit`.